# How to use substring in jQuery for alpha numerics?

Tags: jquery

I have images with name img-1, img-2 and so on.I want to substring it and increment the num and then loop through all the images.How can i achieve it.I use jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess ,not `Substring`,use `split` in this case

```
var splitter= imgName.split('-'); 
var numberString = splitter[1]; //gives second part  .i.e number
var integerNum  =parseInt(numberString); //here numberString converts to integer
integerNum++;  // increment
```

Put the above code in loop and use it .